# ImportError: cannot import name certificate_transparency after installing Pusher

Tags: python, python-2.7, pusher, google-app-engine-python

I created a virtualenv with `virtualenv env`, and then (after sourcing `env/bin/activate`) installed `pusher` with `pip`. However, whenever I try to run my module, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/proc-daemon/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/proc-daemon/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/home/proc-daemon/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/proc-daemon/supachat/supachat.py", line 31, in <module>
    ssl=True
  File "/home/proc-daemon/supachat/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pusher/pusher.py", line 52, in __init__
    json_encoder, json_decoder, backend, **backend_options)
  File "/home/proc-daemon/supachat/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pusher/pusher_client.py", line 34, in __init__
    json_encoder, json_decoder, backend, **backend_options)
  File "/home/proc-daemon/supachat/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pusher/client.py", line 20, in __init__
    from .requests import RequestsBackend
  File "/home/proc-daemon/supachat/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pusher/requests.py", line 17, in <module>
    import urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
  File "/home/proc-daemon/supachat/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/home/proc-daemon/supachat/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/home/proc-daemon/supachat/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 12, in <module>
    from cryptography import x509
  File "/home/proc-daemon/supachat/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/x509/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509 import certificate_transparency
ImportError: cannot import name certificate_transparency
```

All the dependencies installed correctly, and `ls env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/x509` **shows** (among others) `certificate_transparency.pyc` (and `.py`).

Is there a different way to install `pusher` that I am not realizing?

Comment: Are you sure that all dependencies were installed successfuly?

Comment: Yes. `Successfully installed asn1crypto-0.24.0 certifi-2018.8.24 cffi-1.11.5 chardet-3.0.4 cryptography-2.3.1 enum34-1.1.6 idna-2.7 ipaddress-1.0.22 markdown-3.0.1 ndg-httpsclient-0.5.1 pusher-2.0.1 pyasn1-0.4.4 pycparser-2.19 pyopenssl-18.0.0 pytz-2018.5 requests-2.19.1 six-1.11.0 urllib3-1.23`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*So, this doesn't* explain *the problem, but it solves it.*

I was using the wrong backend. Importing `pusher.gae` and setting `backend=pusher.gae.GAEBackend` solved the problem.